# Разбить датафрейм на несколько частей по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется датафрейм, в котором значения в 1 столбце последовательно повторяются и разделены одной, не имеющей значения, строкой

```
>>> df['a'].values.tolist()
>>> ['количество', 'итог', 'лишнее', 'количество', 'итог']
```

Количество значений в датафрейме может быть любое, но гарантировано, что есть как минимум 2 повторяющиеся части и одна лишняя строка, которая их разделяет (значение этой строки тоже может быть произвольным).

Как разделить такой датафрейм на несколько частей, при этом чтоб во втором датафрейме повторялись названия столбцов как в первом

Пример для использования

```
q = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['количество', 23, 45], ['итог', 100, 120], ['лишнее', 'лишнее', 'лишнее'], ['количество', 35, 87], ['итог', 76, 90]]
qw = pd.DataFrame(q, columns=q[0])
qw = qw[1:]
qw
```

Нужно получить два датафрейма

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['количество', 23, 45], ['итог', 100, 120]]
```

и

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['количество', 35, 87], ['итог', 76, 90]]
```

Comment: поставил вопросу плюс - никогда не думал. что буду благодарен просто за годно заданный вопрос.

Comment: а что значит "разделить такой датафрейм на `несколько` частей, при этом чтоб во `втором` датафрейме повторялись названия" - так "несколько" или "два"? Если "два" - то как делить по фреймам пары "количество-итого", если их не 2?

Comment: И непонятно, 'количество', 'итог' - это устойчивые значения или тоже могут меняться, как и 'лишнее'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы рекомендовал поработать с индексами. например, так:

```
df = df[df["a"]!="лишнее"]
res = [g[1] for g in df.groupby(df.index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum())]
```

смотрим, что теперь в `res`:

```
[print(x, type(x), sep="\n") for x in res]
```

```
            a    b    c
0  количество   23   45
1        итог  100  120
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
            a   b   c
3  количество  35  87
4        итог  76  90
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

иными словами, если вы специально не меняли индекс фрейма, то он у вас идет от 0 до какого-то числа с инкрементом в `1`. удаляем строки с ключевым словом и группируем по последовательно идущим индексам. voilà!

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так чтоли:

```
import pandas as pd

q = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['количество', 23, 45], ['итог', 100, 120], ['лишнее', 34, 65], ['количество', 35, 87], ['итог', 76, 90]]
dataframes = []
data = []
check = set()
columns = q[0]
for item in q[1:]:
    if item[0] in check:
        dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(data=data[:-1], columns=columns))
        data = []
        check = set()
    check.update([item[0]])
    data.append(item)
if data:
    dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns))
    
dataframes
```

Вывод:

```
[            a    b    c
 0  количество   23   45
 1        итог  100  120,
             a   b   c
 0  количество  35  87
 1        итог  76  90]
```

Comment: а если получается так, список первого столбца будет следующий ['количество', 'итог', 'количество', 'итог',  'лишнее', 'количество', 'итог',  'количество', 'итог']. в этом случае должно получиться все равно два датафрейма

Comment: А 'лишнее' никогда не повторяется? Тогда алгоритм другой будет, конечно. Тогда надо считать с помощью `Counter` эти штуки и потом идти до того момента, когда встретится штука, которая только один раз насчиталась. Но в целом примерно также будет выглядеть код.

Comment: строка разделения датафреймов не повторяется